# Google Maps Geocoder error on iPhone

Tags: iphone, geocoding

I'm forward geocoding on an ASP.NET site, and I have the following JS:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address, 'region': 'uk' }, function (results, status) {
    alert(status);
    ....
```

In desktop, this alerts `OK`, but on iPhone 6 (through browserstack) it alerts `ERROR`. I'm having huge difficulty debugging iPhone through browserstack, as I don't own any Apple devices, so was hoping somebody would have some insight here.

If nobody has seen this before, perhaps somebody might know how I can find more information about the error?

**Edit:** Even more confusing, the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=en) show possible `status` response values as `OK`, `ZERO_RESULTS`, `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`, `REQUEST_DENIED`, `INVALID_REQUEST` or `UNKNOWN_ERROR`. My alert just shows `ERROR`...

Comment: Have you looked into `results`? It might have a more detailed error message

Comment: Tried, it alerts an object in desktop where it works, but doesn't alert anything on iPhone, so I assume it's undefined? **Edit:** Nvm, I got null.